# Why is ACF giving me the wrong output data for image?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Using advanced custom fields for Wordpress to allow the client to upload images to parts of a page. Everything worked fine when it was handed off but now all the ACF related images are not displaying.

Here is is the current output of the image.
Notice the crazy src url:

```
<img data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="500" data-aos-duration="600" data-src="https://notmychurchbook.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/the-book.png" class="image lazyload aos-init aos-animate" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==">
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the console error. issues with lazy load images. Or disable lazy load plugin, theme feature.

Comment: Are you saying this IS an issue with lazy loading? There are no errors in the console.

Comment: Yes its is lazy load issue !

Comment: or can be optimization plugin conflicts.

Comment: Actually it was related to the wp-smush plugin. Do you know how to fix it possibly?

Comment: Need to debug the issue! if with wp-smush

Comment: also try to play with aos animation